# Android Error: cannot be cast

Tags: java, android

What is wrong with this code?

Receitas.java

```
// File Receitas.java
public class Receitas extends Application {

    ArrayList<Receita> mReceitas;
    ArrayList<String> mTipoReceitas;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mReceitas = new ArrayList<>();
        mTipoReceitas = new ArrayList<>();
   }

}
```

InsertActivity.java

```
public class InsertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

// ...

Receitas receitas = (Receitas) getApplication();

// ...
```

}

When I try this code on AndroidStudio I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.android.vegeeat.model.Receitas
```

Comment: `Receitas extends Application` means `Receitas` is a kind of `Application`, but the `Application` does not have to be a `Receitas`.

Comment: it's a mess in terms of android development

Comment: Did you specify `Receitas` in the `name` attribute on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: Receitas is a kind of Application :|

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Try this way

```
public class Receitas extends Application {

// Singleton instance
private static Receitas sInstance = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Setup singleton instance
        sInstance = this;
    }

    // Getter to access Singleton instance
    public static Receitas getInstance() {
        return sInstance ; 
    }
    }
```

Now

InsertActivity.java

```
public class InsertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements         
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    // ...

    Receitas receitas = (Receitas) Receitas.getInstance();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to all who responded. Mike M.'s answer solved the problem.